# Why java final variable showing unreachable Statement

Tags: java, variables, local, final

```
class Temp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int x=10,y=20;
        while (x<y)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

output 
it prints Hello infinity times

but when i make local variable final int x=10,y=20;
then it is showing Statement Unreachable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making those variables `final` also makes them constant variables. That means the compiler can replace the use of the variables with the value they are initialized with.

As such, the compiler attempts to produce the following

```
while (10 < 20)
```

This is equivalent to

```
while (true)
```

That will make it an infinite loop and the code that comes after the block will become unreachable.

This is specified in the Java Language Specification, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

> A while statement can complete normally iff at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> - **The while statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.**
> - There is a reachable break statement that exits the while statement.

None of those is satisfied, so the `while` statement cannot complete normally. Everything after it is unreachable.

Comment: You can make it reachable again by putting a `if(somethingThatTheCompilerCannotReasonAbout) break;` into the loop.

Comment: also ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4 to know about constant variables.  if you do int `a = 10;   final int x=10+a;` then x is no more a constant variable and even  `while (x == x)` will execute in infinite loop.

Comment: That is a clear explanation of how the compiler knows the second println is unreachable when the variables are final. But it leaves the question: why can't it figure out that that line is still unreachable when the variables are mutable? There is no assignment to them in the body of the loop, and surely Java knows such method-local variables can't be modified from inside the call to println in the loop body. So is it just that the compiler doesn't bother evaluating reachability if the condition isn't constant? ('Cause, you know, Halting Problem?)

Comment: @DanBron It probably _could_, but Java chooses not to go that deep.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing unreachable cause since both `x` and `y` are declared `final`, there is no way they are going to change (they are constants), so the while will ALWAYS loop, and the "Hi" print will never be reached

Answer (score 0):

Java knows that final variables cannot be changed. You've declared `x,y` to both be final. Therefore it knows that the loop cannot terminate, because `x < y` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your example the final variables are `initialized with a compile-time constant expression`. making them constant variables, the compiler knows it can never be changed during run time. Thus `final int x =10, y=20` become constant variables known from the compile time.

which is equivalent to :

```
  while (10<20){
         System.out.println("Hello");
     }
  System.out.println("Hi");
```

Now the compile time evaluation tells that the statement  `System.out.println("Hi");` will be unreachable in this case.

where as  `non constant variables` can be changed during run time. So no compile time check for the while condition.

for more ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4